# What's the difference between File.toURI vs Uri.fromFile in Android

Tags: android

While trying to get a picture using a Camera intent as describe in the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/camera.html#intents).
I've added the required `MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT` extra but the problem was that it didn't save the file where I wanted. So I read the documentation more carefully, and compared it with what I was doing (since I didn't blindly copy/pasted the provided sample code), and found that I was using

```
intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, myFile.toURI());
```

Instead of

```
intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, Uri.fromFile(myFile));
```

The second version worked perfectly, but I can't figure out why. The documentation for both methods don't state anything related to incompatibility between the two.

Shouldn't the two give the same result, or am I missing a subtle difference?

Comment: i think there is a difference between Uri and URI

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The content produced by Uri.fromFile() and file.toURI() is not the same...

for the same file "f" located on the sdcard.

"f.toURI()" will add this into your Bundle `{output=file:/mnt/sdcard/Gp/Gp.db}`

and "Uri.fromFile(f)" will add `{output=file:///mnt/sdcard/Gp/Gp.db}`

Answer (score 4):

Just from a quick test here:

Uri.fromFile() returns a Uri (android.net.Uri)

file.toURI() returns a URI (java.net.URI)

I expect this is causing the problem.